# After resuming my laptop it is unlocked for a while before locking

Tags: 12.10, laptop, lock-screen

When I close my laptop lid and it is suspended, when I open it again it is resumed but without showing the lock screen which is set to come up. It resumes with access to web pages or programs that were left open. I can use my laptop to continue with what I had open for between a few seconds to about half a minute at which point the lock screen will come up. I would much prefer it if the lock screen would show when the lid is opened.

My laptop is a Zoostorm Freedom 10-270 Netbook, with Intel Atom N270 (1.6GHz). It is running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to tell us the model of your laptop? Therefore we can have a look at the specifications etc. Not a very good question at current.

Comment: Thanks for adding details.  I am voting to have this question re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems out of the ordinary about that laptop except that that Atom chip is very, very slow.  Maybe this is making an existing bug more obvious, as in, it should normally lock upon resume a lot faster?

A workaround might be to lock the screen with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` before you close the laptop screen?